# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column but tge column exists

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1054

in my php file I am running the following code :

```
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM `bcpd` WHERE `bcpdID`=' . $bcpdID);
```

where `bcpdID` can be only numbers, or characters. The problem is: when `bcpdID` is a number, the code works, but when there is letters, it shows the error `1054`.

I am not expert in PHP and MySql so I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: *but when there is letters, it shows the error 1054* 1) String literal must be wrapped with single quotes in final query text. 2) You must citate the whole error message - the tale about it is not useful.

Comment: Let’s see when the #1054 error occurs in MySQL. While inserting a varchar value, if you will forget to add single quotes, then this error will arise. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/why-the-hash1054-unknown-column-error-occurs-in-mysql-and-how-to-fix-it

Comment: Your query should be something like `$reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM bcpd WHERE bcpdID='" . $bcpdID."'");`

Comment: @UmairKhan no, please, NEVER. Use prepared statements, never recommend anything else that is unsecure and leads to SQL injections

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM `bcpd` WHERE `bcpdID`= '$bcpdID'");
```

Comment: No, please, NEVER use such a query. Use prepared statements, never recommend anything else that is insecure and leads to SQL injections